# Get default value of a field for every sub-documents in a arrayfield in mongo

Tags: arrays, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have my documents like this -

```
{
    "Details": "WorkProfile" : [
                        {
                                "Company" : "UPS",
                                "JobTitle" : "Preload Package Handler",
                                "JobSkills" : {
                                        "CommonSkills" : [
                                                ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e911e")
                                        ],
                                        "OtherSkills" : [
                                                ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9208")
                                        ]
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "Company" : "L&L Tent and Party",
                                "JobTitle" : "Delivery Driver/ Tent Installation",
                                "JobSkills" : {
                                        "CommonSkills" : [
                                                ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9227")
                                        ],
                                        "OtherSkills" : [ ]
                                }
                        },
                        {
                                "Company" : "All Pro Movers",
                                "JobTitle" : "Mover"
                        },
                        {
                                "Company" : "Carolina Farmin",
                                "JobTitle" : "Head of Cullinary"
                        }
                ],

}
```

I want to fetch `OtherSkills` for every sub-document in `WorkProfile`section. I have tried the following

```
db.Collection.aggregate([{$match: {"DocId": "669f4a8f-13cd-4780-8115-e3f29b0d9b4f"}}, {$project: {"JobSkills": "$Details.WorkProfile.JobSkills.OtherSkills"}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5ab89af2808b739ba6aac"),
        "JobSkills" : [
                [
                        ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9208")
                ],
                [ ]
        ]
}
```

Now I want to set a default value for the field, if the field doesn't exists in that sub-document. For this I tried using [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) command like this

```
 db.ResumeParsedData.aggregate([{$match: {"DocId": "669f4a8f-13cd-4780-8115-e3f29b0d9b4f"}}, {$project: {"JobSkills": {$ifNull: ["$ResumeDetails.WorkProfile.JobSkills.OtherSkills", "null"]}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5ab89af2808b739ba6aac"),
        "JobSkills" : [
                [
                        ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9208")
                ],
                [ ]
        ]
}
```

But I am getting the same result as in my first query. How should I specify a default value to the field if the field doesn't exists in the sub-document.

I am expecting this output for the above said document -

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ad5ab89af2808b739ba6aac"),
    "JobSkills" : [
            [
                    ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9208")
            ],
            [ ],
            "null",
            "null"
    ]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to transform an array using [$ifNull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/index.html)

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "JobSkills": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$Details.WorkProfile",
                    as: "p",
                    in: { $ifNull: [ "$$p.JobSkills.OtherSkills", "null" ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : ...,
    "JobSkills" : [
            [
                    ObjectId("5ad5ab860b94c96c738e9208")
            ],
            [ ],
            "null",
            "null"
    ]
}
```